# Create a trigger that prevents a deletion of tables with less than 20 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to create a trigger that will raise an error If someone tries to delete a Row in a table containing less than 20 rows. I am farely new to triggers, the following code is where I have come to a halt.

```
Create or Replace Trigger Lab16Trigger2
BEFORE Delete On employee_copy
WHEN (count(*) < 20)

Begin
  RAISERROR('ORA-20101: At least 20 rows in employee_copy table');

End;
```

Comment: What do you mean "delete a table"?  That really isn't a SQL operation.  You can delete *rows* in a table.  Or, you can *drop* a table.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Or a real problem?  In a real system, a trigger would not be the proper solution unless this is a single-user system .

Comment: This is the final question on my lab. I have everything finished except for this one. He tries to challenge us by asking a question we have not covered in class. This is as far as I have gotten so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a homework assignment (the requirement doesn't generally make sense and a trigger won't work in a multi-user environment)

```
create or replace trigger trigger_name
  after delete on table_name
declare
  l_cnt pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from table_name;

  if( l_cnt < 20 )
  then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'You must leave at least 20 rows in the table.' );
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, I just now realized that the when clause in the trigger statement  only applies to rows and not a table as a whole.